# What is the right tool to MPC linear equations system

Tags: multiparty-computation, data-privacy

Given two parties who have private inputes

Player 1 - $X_1,...X_n$ 
Player 2 - $Y_1,...Y_n$

We want to compute a solution to a linear system equation:

$f_1(X_1,...X_n,...Y_1,...Y_n) +h_1(X_1,...X_n)+g_1(Y_1,...Y_n) = 0 \bmod p$

...

$f_{2n}(X_1,...X_n,...Y_1,...Y_n) +h_{2n}(X_1,...X_n)+g_{2n}(Y_1,...Y_n)= 0 \bmod p$

where $f_i$ are a linear function for  $1 \leq i \leq 2n$

What is the best (MPC) tool to compute the solution of that system between the two parties, in the semi-honest adversry model?
- I appreciate a survery of approaches to that kind of question.

Comment: Define "best". What kind of information do you require for a "survey"?

Comment: efficient in terms of communication and time comlexity.  "survey"-just "enumaration" of top 3 option